# Foundry HelperConfig Error"Member "priceFeedETHUSD" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function"

Tags: foundry

I got this error when I wanted to add config to the deploy script

```
Compiler run failed:
Error (9582): Member "priceFeedETHUSD" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function () view external returns (address,address).
  --> script/DeployAMMTest.s.sol:12:29:
   |
12 |         address priceFeed = helperConfig.config.priceFeedETHUSD;
```

The HelperConfig Code was

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.22;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {MockV3Aggregator} from "../test/Mock/MockV3Aggregator.sol";

contract HelperConfig is Script {
    NetworkConfig public config;

    uint8 public constant DECIMALS = 8;
    int256 public constant INITIAL_PRICE = 2000e8;

    struct NetworkConfig {
        address priceFeedETHUSD;
        address priceFeedBTCUSD;
    }

    constructor() {
        if (block.chainid == 1) {
            config = getMainnetConfig();
        } else if (block.chainid == 11155111) {
            config = getSepoliaConfig();
        } else {
            config = getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig();
        }
    }

    function getSepoliaConfig() public pure returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        return
            NetworkConfig({
                priceFeedETHUSD: 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306,
                priceFeedBTCUSD: 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306
            });
    }

    function getMainnetConfig() public pure returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        return
            NetworkConfig({
                priceFeedETHUSD: 0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419,
                priceFeedBTCUSD: 0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419
            });
    }

    function getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig() public returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        if (config.priceFeedETHUSD != address(0)) {
            return config;
        }

        vm.startBroadcast();
        MockV3Aggregator mockPriceFeed = new MockV3Aggregator(
            DECIMALS,
            INITIAL_PRICE
        );
        vm.stopBroadcast();
        return
            NetworkConfig({
                priceFeedETHUSD: address(mockPriceFeed),
                priceFeedBTCUSD: address(mockPriceFeed)
            });
    }
}
```

And the Deploy Code was below:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.22;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {AMMTest} from "../src/AMMTest.sol";
import {HelperConfig} from "./HelperConfig.s.sol";

contract DeployAMMTest is Script {
    function run() external {
        HelperConfig helperConfig = new HelperConfig();
        address priceFeed = helperConfig.config.priceFeedETHUSD;
        vm.startBroadcast();
        AMMTest ammTest = new AMMTest(priceFeed);
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity has limitations in handling direct member access of a struct returned from a function in another contract. This is due to visibility and scope rules in Solidity concerning structs.

Solution:

Update HelperConfig Contract:

Add a function to return the priceFeedETHUSD directly, avoiding direct struct member access.

```
function getPriceFeedETHUSD() public view returns (address) {
    return config.priceFeedETHUSD;
}
```

Update DeployAMMTest Contract:

Modify the contract to call the newly added function instead of accessing the struct member directly.

```
contract DeployAMMTest is Script {
    function run() external {
        HelperConfig helperConfig = new HelperConfig();
        address priceFeed = helperConfig.getPriceFeedETHUSD(); // Updated line
        vm.startBroadcast();
        AMMTest ammTest = new AMMTest(priceFeed);
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

This change resolves the visibility issue by accessing the price feed address through a function call, which is a more standard and safer method in Solidity for accessing data across different contracts.